# Read variable inside a quote for count

Tags: pandas, variables, quote

I am struggling to use variable inside a quote. My search is pointing only to the  application for printing a string that contains a variable.

```
w='red'
bb2['vs'].str.count(r'\b$$\b')
```

My requirement is to substitute variable 'w' at the place of $$.

Thanks

Comment: (1) You need to escape the dollar signs since they are otherwise a metacharacter.  (2) Dollar-sign literals don't make a ton of sense with word boundaries, frankly.  Are you saying, "dollar signs surround by white space"? or something else?

Comment: I have used $$ just for explanation. I would like to have count(r'\bred\b') when w='red'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
w = 'red'
def repl(x):
    if x.contains(r'\b$$\b'):
        x.replace('$$', w)
    return x

bbs['vs'] = bbs['vs'].apply(repl)
```